# Best practice for logging into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, logging

I am working on an IoT project where our devices will send (one way) text (JSON) logs to our servers for storing them in DB for further our specialists analyzing.

I am wondering whether I should care about special presets for the DB (**PostgreSQL**) to keep system alive?
There is list of requirements the system must comply with:

1. write around **5b** of records (5 columns with a FK in a one) 
   per annum. Why per annum? Because the records can be given all in
   the same day (for sure it is the worst case I could imagine, but it,
   in abstract, possible). More real it is about **20m-50m** records
   (we use an average logs dump from a number of devices for a  few
   days). Records can be given even all (20m-50m) at once (withing an
   hour) or during the day.
2. use cron to remove outdated logs from
   the pgsql once per day.
3. make SELECT for records per `device ID`
   (FK) withing a `specified time period` **up to 500 times** a day.
4. The DB will keep logs only for the last 12 months. So in total it should not exceed 5b of records.

I have a regular database withing the PostgreSQL and am looking whether do I need to create another one for logging or can stick with current?

Now I am about to just create another table for logging and proceed like as with the rest project data. But I doubt if it is correct in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use a trigger to clean out old rows. You pay the price of the trigger overhead for **each and every** insert. Run a `cron` job in the night that cleans out old rows and get rid of the trigger.

Comment: You can potentially partition the table by time as well, which would make removing old records as easy as dropping the old tables. Can also be beneficial if your queries will only look at subsets of the table based on a time range